# When do Tensorflow distributed workers submit to the parameter server?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I read a lot about the distributed execution of training a neural network in tensorflow. Especially on this page
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SyncReplicasOptimizer

But i could not find an answer to my wuestion. Does a worker sync its gradients after finishing the calculations of each variable? Or does it wait till it finishes all the variables then sync with the PS?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, all the gradients will be updated at the end of the calculationat once. However there is paper which makes pipelining the process of backpropagation, so it accelerate the speed of the performance.

Comment: What do you mean by pipelining?

Comment: I mean pipelining the back propagation layer by layer

Comment: So is this currently implemented in tensorflow?

Comment: Nop, the paper what i mentioned is framework above tensorflow as i know, current tensorflow might sync all the gradients at the end of the calculation.